# Pandas: Apply function to dataframe column and object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function

I am trying to apply the following function to a dataframe column:

```
def extract_text_similarity_jaccard (text1, text2):
    nr = len(set(text1).intersection(set(text2)))

    dr = len(set(text1).union(set(text2)))

    jaccard_sim = nr/dr

    return jaccard_sim

text = ['prior', 'canopy', 'removal']

df['jac_sim'] = extract_text_similarity_jaccard(df['Processed'], text)
df['jac_sim']
```

However it returns 0.0 when there are similarities. I think this is due to the way I am trying to compare the df column with the 'text' object, however would appreciate any guidance on how to correct the code!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
df['jac_sim'] = df.apply(lambda x: extract_text_similarity_jaccard(x['Processed'], text), axis=1)
```

Your current way of calling the function passes the pandas Series to the first argument of the function.  Calling in the way suggested above should perform a vectorized operation of by passing elements to the function.

### Edit

Created some test data and run the codes:

```
data = {'Processed': [['prior', 'canopy', 'removal'], ['prior', 'removal'], ['prior', 'canopy', 'removal', 'apple'], ['orange', 'canopy',  'apple'], ['prior', 'canopy', 'peach', 'apple']]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

    Processed
0   [prior, canopy, removal]
1   [prior, removal]
2   [prior, canopy, removal, apple]
3   [orange, canopy, apple]
4   [prior, canopy, peach, apple]

# Run your code:
df['jac_sim'] = extract_text_similarity_jaccard(df['Processed'], text)

Output:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-104-04f79e3031d8> in <module>
----> 1 df['jac_sim'] = extract_text_similarity_jaccard(df['Processed'], text)

<ipython-input-103-a35ebcf514df> in extract_text_similarity_jaccard(text1, text2)
      1 def extract_text_similarity_jaccard (text1, text2):
----> 2     nr = len(set(text1).intersection(set(text2)))
      3 
      4     dr = len(set(text1).union(set(text2)))
      5 

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'


#Run my code:

df['jac_sim'] = df.apply(lambda x: extract_text_similarity_jaccard(x['Processed'], text), axis=1)

                         Processed   jac_sim
0         [prior, canopy, removal]  1.000000
1                 [prior, removal]  0.666667
2  [prior, canopy, removal, apple]  0.750000
3          [orange, canopy, apple]  0.200000
4    [prior, canopy, peach, apple]  0.400000
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, unfortunately it still returns 0.0 where for example i know line 4 should register some similarity `0    0.0
1    0.0
2    0.0
3    0.0
4    0.0
5    0.0
6    0.0
7    0.0
8    0.0
Name: jac_sim, dtype: float64`

Comment: Please provide some data samples.

Comment: @Jon,  I have created some data myself and tested with correct result.  Please let me know whether your data is in the same format as above.  In particular, whether the elements in column `Processed` contain lists of strings or not.